# How to inline CSS and JavaScript in the application.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The default Rails 3.2 `application.html.erb` is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testapp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to inline the asset pipeline generated CSS and JavaScript here?

*PS: No need to lament that inlining could be a bad idea.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout template, replace

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

with,

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
<%= Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.js').body.html_safe %>
</script>
```